# problem with the get variable

Tags: php, javascript, post, get

this is my form

```
<form name="thumbnail" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>?complete=true" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" id="x1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" id="y1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" id="x2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" id="y2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" id="w" />
            <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" id="h" />
            <input style="margin-top:7px;" type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save Thumbnail" id="save_thumb" />
        </form>
```

and on the page i have this

```
<?php
 print_r($_GET);

  if($_GET["complete"] == "true"){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
</script>
 <?php } ?>
```

but the get is always nothing..why is that when i add ?complete=true to the string

i tried GET POST but nothing....any ideas on how to do this

Comment: You have the form method as POST, which doesn't send anything to GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me...

```
Array
(
    [complete] => true
)
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
</script>
```

So you have a problem somewhere else.

Also, if you are going to use `<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>` for your form, change it to `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` for security.

Otherwise, I may request `index.php/"%20onsubmit="alert('xss');return%20false"%20bla="` which leaves your HTML looking like....

```
<form name="thumbnail" action="/stuff/euler.php/" onsubmit="alert('xss');return false" bla="?complete=true" method="post">
```

Comment: click the upload image and its an iframe and i need it to shut the iframe afte the image gets cropped

Comment: @Tamer When you get back to `modal.php` after uploading, it doesn't have the GET param anymore.

Comment: in the form it has    <form name="thumbnail" action="/test/modal.php?complete=true" method="post">

Comment: @Tamer Because after upload, you send the header `Location: http://comfortrevolution.com/test/modal.php` which doesn't have the GET param. If you want to persist its state over the `Location` header, you will need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try === instead of ==

I would guess the string "true" gets evaluated as true (boolean)